# Updating emails in a Shared Mailbox using an Azure Client Application and Microsoft Graph SDK

Tags: microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

I'm trying to update email categories of items in a Shared Mailbox using Microsoft Graph SDK.

This is the code used to create the Graph SDK Client. It uses the Azure Client Application credentials (ClientId, TenantId, Secret):

```
var handlers = GraphClientFactory.CreateDefaultHandlers(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async msg =>
{
    var accessToken = await GetAccessTokenFromCacheOrRefresh(cancellationToken);
    msg.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
}));

handlers.Add(_graphLoggingHandler);

var httpClient = GraphClientFactory.Create(handlers);
_graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(httpClient);
```

This is the code used to update the message categories:

```
    var updatedMessage = new Message();
    updatedMessage.Categories = CreateMessageCategories();
    await _graphServiceClient.Users[emailAddress].Messages[emailId]
        .Request()
        .UpdateAsync(updatedMessage, cancellationToken);
```

When I run this code, I get the error "Access Denied". What permissions do I need to update messages in this Shared MailBox? The Administrators tell me I can't use `Mail.ReadWrite` on the Application level because that will allow the application to modify emails in *all* mailboxes.

Answer (score 0):

When the app is configured with application permissions, then the app has access to all mailboxes by default.

Tenant administrators can create an [application access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access#configure-applicationaccesspolicy) by using the `New-ApplicationAccessPolicy` PowerShell cmdlet to limit an app to only specific mailboxes and not all Exchange Online mailboxes in the organization.

More details:

[Limiting application permissions to specific Exchange Online mailboxes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access)